# Can you branch off another water line source rather than a main line

Tags: plumbing

finishing my laundry room in my basement and originally I just had a 1/2 hot and cold water line running to my laundry and I'm not adding a utility sink to my laundry room which will be in front of my washer.

Is it ok if I have my main line run to my utility sink into a wye then to my washer, compared to running the main line to washer and branching off extra pipe to my utility sink?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: Are you talking about supply (water), or drain (waste) plumbing?